# Set UITableViewCell selected to YES in willDisplayCell: and the cell can't be deselected anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to pre-select some rows in a multiple selection UITableView.

I do this in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` by simply setting `[cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];`.

However, for some reason this disables deselection for these rows. The embedded controls still work, and so do detail disclosure buttons.

I have uploaded a sample project here: https://github.com/leberwurstsaft/TableViewIssue where you can check out the behavior (in `Viewcontroller.m` lines 49-51).

```c
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:NO]; //   -->   setSelected:YES and the cells can't be deselected anymore...
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this in view did appear,  work for me

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

in your viewController.h add and link it to the table view

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

and comment the line in willDisplayCell Function

Comment: Like someone else on IRC already pointed out, you shall never set the selection state yourself, but let the tableView do it. And the right place for that is anywhere after you call -reloadData on your tableView, or for example in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I know this is old, but @leberwurstsaft comment had me worried about using `selectRow`. I found this statement in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9). "For situations like these, you can use the UITableView methods selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:..." I feel much more confident about manually selecting a row in this way now.

Comment: The sample misses the call to super (which in case of table view controller would flash the scroll indicators) but the main issue is viewDidAppear is only called when the table view was added to a window. So depending on how your view controllers are created this might not work.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to setting the cell as selected, you also need to inform the tableView that the cell is selected. Add a call to `-tableView:selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` to your `willDisplayCell:` method: and you will be able to deselect it as normal.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (/*should be selected */) {
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO]; 
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

This is similar to @Ivan Loya's solution, but can be done in the same method you were already using. Be sure to use `UITableViewScrollPositionNone` to avoid odd scrolling behavior.

Comment: You, my friend, I owe you a beer ! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Why do you need to keep first line? [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO]; I think that it doesn't really do any work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your selection in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and toggle in there the selection.

Here is what I do in a similar situation where I want to toggle the checkmark on each row

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    Person * person = [self.contactTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        {
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            person.isMatch = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            self.countChecked ++ ;


        }else
        {
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            person.isMatch = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            self.countChecked -- ;
        }
}
```

Comment: Although possibly relevant, this really does not solve the issue. He wants to **preselect** cells. Not just edit a selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering in iOS 11 how to fix this:

Drew C, Got it right, But Im translating it to Swift:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if cell.isSelected {
        cell.isSelected = true
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```